# angularjs check if array value is in another array

Tags: angularjs

I have the problem that I need to find which of the letters in the alphabet is true and which is false.

I can't change the array $available (comes from a response).

indexOf does not work because it looks only at the index values 0 & 1 but it have to look at the values...

any idea how to fix that?

**Here my pseudo code:**

```
var $alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
var $available = [0: 'a', 1: 'b'];
var $templateglossar = [];

  angular.forEach($available, function(letter) {
    if($alphabet.indexOf(letter) > -1) {
      $templateglossar.push(letter => true);
    } else {
      $templateglossar.push(letter => false);
    }
  });
```

Comment: post your excepted output @Van Fanel

Comment: can you please elaborate the $available, display few more elements of $available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions for your issue.

1:

```
if($alphabet.indexOf($available[letter]) > -1)
```

2:

```
angular.forEach($available, function(key, letter) {...});
```

Comment: 2: solved my Problem thanks

angular.forEach($available, function(key, letter) {...});

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can specify both the key and the value in a forEach, like this :

```
angular.forEach(objectToIterate, function(value, key) {
    /* do something for all key: value pairs */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe take a look to this lib (lodash): expeccialy to the _.difference() method:

(link to doc)

```
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#difference
```

for example in your case something like:

```
var $alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
var $available = [0: 'a', 1: 'b'];
var $templateglossar = [];

$templateglossar = _.difference($alphabet, $available);
```

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: Nice libs but I don't knew how to get it work with angular

Comment: just add i in your Index.html as any ohtner js lib (and you DON'T HAVE to inject it in..but only use it ... very simple :-)